# Outputting a column as a different number from a different table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

The goal is to rank the Movies table according to quantity in the Inventory table such that for each duplicate value, it skips the subsequent value so that the next non-duplicate value remains in its rightful position.  Display MovieID, Latest Title, Price, and the Rank.

WhileMovieId ‘1’ from Movies table corresponds to MovieId ‘101’ of your Movie inventory table and so on.

These are the tables

Movies

| MovieId | latest title | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Breaking Dawn | 200.00 |
| 2 | The Proposal | 185.00 |
| 3 | Iron Man 2 | 180.00 |
| 4 | Up | 180.00 |
| 5 | The Karate Kid | 190.00 |
| 6 | How to train your Dragon | 190.00 |
| 7 | Spiderman 3 | 195.00 |

Movie Inventory

| MovieId | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 3 |
| 105 | 4 |
| 107 | 5 |
| 108 | 7 |
| 110 | 8 |
| 111 | 4 |

And this is my attempt at the code that is showing a lot of NULL

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN Movies.MovieId + 100 = MovieInventory.MovieID 
        THEN CAST(MovieInventory.MovieID AS INT) 
        END AS 'MovieId',

    Movies.LatestTitle, Movies.Price,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Movies.MovieId DESC) AS [Rank]
FROM Movies, MovieInventory WHERE MovieInventory.MovieID IS NOT NULL
GO
```

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). This is a good example of the problems created by an accidental cross-join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need.

Notes:

- **You need `RANK` not `DENSE_RANK` to achieve the result you want**
- **You need to order by `Quantity`**
- Use proper `JOIN` syntax, not comma `,` joins
- Use table aliases for better readability
- The foreign and primary key relationships are weird: `mi.MovieID` appears to be `varchar` but when converted to `int` is 100 more than `m.MovieID`???
- The calculation in the `SELECT` is not accessible to the `JOIN` conditions
- Don't use apostrophes `''` to quote column names

```sql
SELECT
    mi.MovieId,
    m.LatestTitle,
    m.Price,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY mi.Quantity DESC) AS [Rank]
FROM Movies m
JOIN MovieInventory mi ON TRY_CAST(mi.MovieID AS int) = m.MovieID + 100;
```